# Partial fractions for $\left (\frac{z^2+1}{z^2-1} \right )^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to decompose this function: $$\left (\frac{z^2+1}{z^2-1}  \right )^2$$ into partial fractions.
What I've done up to now is this:
$$\frac{z^2+1}{(z-1)(z+1)}=\frac{A}{z-1}+\frac{B}{z+1}$$
Which doesn't give me the correct $A$ and $B$.
What is wrong with the not-squared experssion?

Comment: The deg on top and bottom are the same.  Divide first then partial fractions.

Comment: For a partial fraction decomposition, the degree of the numerator must be strictly smaller than the degree of the denominator. Write $$\frac{z^2+1}{z^2-1} = 1 + \frac{2}{(z-1)(z+1)} = 1 + \frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z+1}.$$

Comment: In partial fractions, the degree of the numerator (top) must be less than the degree of the denominator (bottom). In your case, the degree is 2 for each. Start by writing $z^2+1 = z^2-1+2$ and do a division first. Now do partial fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{z^2+1}{z^2-1}=1+\frac{2}{z^2-1}=1+\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1}\tag{1}$$
hence by squaring the previous line:
$$\left(\frac{z^2+1}{z^2-1}\right)^2 = 1+\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}+\frac{2}{z-1}-\frac{2}{z+1}-\frac{2}{z^2-1}\tag{2}$$
so, using $(1)$ again:
$$\left(\frac{z^2+1}{z^2-1}\right)^2 = 1+\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}+\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you give me a hint for decomposing $\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}$?

Comment: @UdiBehar: the hint is to rename $z$ as $i\cdot t$.

Comment: Works. Thanks .